# Não consigo remover uma referência instalada pelo NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Instalei a `DLL` `Log4net` pelo `nuget`. Como está em uma versão diferente da nossa e um colega me passou a usual, deletei ela da pasta e coloquei a atual. Quando eu buildo a solution/projeto, a versão que foi instalada pelo `NuGet` volta. Como eu faço para remover e deixar a antiga, mesmo dando build? A opção `uninstall` não aparece quando eu abro o `NuGet`(somente `Install`).

Comment: Tenta isso no console unInstall-Package log4net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abra o *Package Manager Console* e execute o seguinte comando:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package log4net
```

Todas as referências ao log4net serão removidas corretamente.